# How to make a smooth transition from one state to another SplitView UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to make a smooth transition from a closed panel to an open panel and vice versa.

But I don't know how to do it ((

I have an element

```
<SplitView Style="{StaticResource SplitViewEditMusicTraskStyle}"               
                   CompactPaneLength="0"
                   PaneBackground="Transparent"
                   DisplayMode="CompactInline"
                   IsPaneOpen="{Binding EditPanelIsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   OpenPaneLength="308"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   PanePlacement="Right">
```

I could not attach the standard element template because stackoverflov has a limit on the number of characters per stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make a smooth transition from one state to another SplitView UWP

During the testing, if set `PanePlacement` right, for making SplitView panel open smoothly, please set DisplyMode as `Overlay` or `CompactOverlay`.

```
<SplitView x:Name="splitView" PaneBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}"
       IsPaneOpen="False" OpenPaneLength="328" CompactPaneLength="56" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
```

For your requirement, you could also make pop control and set `ChildTransitions` as  [`PaneThemeTransition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.panethemetransition?view=winrt-19041) to archive smooth transition from a closed panel to an open panel. For more please refer following code.

Xaml code

```
<Popup
        x:Name="RightMeun"
        Width="200"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        IsOpen="False">

        <Popup.ChildTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Right" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.ChildTransitions>
        <Grid
            Width="200"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=RightMeun, Path=Height}"
            Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Hello" />
        </Grid>
</Popup>
```